# Android Google Map v2 How to call default gesture?

Tags: android, google-maps, gesture

I am very new of gesture design.  In Google map v2 API it allow double tap that detect onDoubleTap gesture to zoom in or out. I have browse some question relate to this issue but it is all base on MapView class instead of GoogleMap that use to create in fragment.  My project is create base on GoogleMap insted of MapView but the time for me is short so I don't want to rewrite the program from begin.

What I want to do is like if I press a button on device (like volume down) and only one finger single tap on screen than can perform zoom gesture.  So I like to ask if it is possible to directly perform gesture without it's default setting? If can, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Zooming operation is performed using 2 fingers that are separated from each other, just like you would zoom an image in your phone. other operations you can monitor on the map object are:

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(arg0);
map.setOnMapClickListener(arg0);
map.setOnMapLongClickListener(arg0);
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(arg0);
map.setOnMarkerDragListener(arg0);
```

If you wan't to perform the zooming using the double-tapping operation then you would have to write the code for it yourself, monitor double-clicks and zoom the map pragmatically if it was performed.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.  As I mention in post, goole map v2 api already included double tap zooming.  So I think write a new code is not a good option. Can I just direclty call this gesutre to perfrom zooming with some behave (like hold device button and one finger single tap on map) instead of writing a new code?

Comment: You can try. Let us know the results.

Comment: Well I checked now and you are right, Google Map API V2 does supports zooming on double tapping. maybe you could use their method by overriding it. but I never tried it and have no idea how it's done.